# Simulating Debris Burn Up Upon Atmospheric Reentry

Tags: energy, mass, space

For work I need to model Debris (1 gram to no more than 1000 km) burn-up upon reentry. I can't seem to find much information regarding this. I feel like I am looking for the wrong terms or something.

Can someone help me to understand more clearly what I should be looking for? Purchasing software, open source, or writing my own algorithm is acceptable. I'm just having difficulty finding a starting point.

Also sorry for the tags apparently there is no 'ablation' or 'reentry' tags...

Comment: The re-entry problem has been mostly analyzed for larger bodies that survive. There us plenty of material for that. Not sure how well it can be adapted for small debris. Did you look at the thickness of the shock wave boundary layer? If it's larger than the debris that you are looking at, then the physics should be markedly different from large bodies, if not, then one can probably use the existing theory. I would bet that it's larger than the debris... but I might be wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure what the "thickness of the shockwave boundary layer" is. I do not currently have any sort of simulation engine more than propagation (takes into account wind, drag, and gravity), though I do have ballistic coefficients, initial velocity, material type, width, length, height, ect.

I'm basically looking for a good starting point. I did manage to find that I believe the term I should be searching for is "aero-thermal demise", but I haven't found a path forward for the project yet.

Comment: You will have to understand hypersonic bow shocks if you want to play with this. Did you look into those? If not, that's your starting point.

Comment: I'm not sure I feel this is a proper starting point. At least in the way you seem to be suggesting it. I'm not looking for a CFD model in the burn-up of debris. There are too many pieces to be doing that talking in the range of 10,000-20,000 per run with there being about 700-3000 runs per study. I am specifically interested in the reduction of mass by the time it reaches the ground.

Comment: Perhaps I am just not following what you are meaning well, but if that is the path forward you are suggesting my starting point would likely be before looking into hypersonic bow shocks.

Comment: You will need some physical model of what happens during the re-entry... there are only two ways to get that: experimentally or by modeling from first principles. You have to find a paper that has done the hard work for you, better multiple papers for both. I don't think there is a canned solution... it's just not a problem that "sells". What is your application?

Comment: Right. That's what I'm trying to find, or software that could be applicable, I've found DAS, ORSAT, and SCARAB. Only DAS seems to just be available. I'm currently reading through http://www.sinphi.com/TroyOwens_Thesis_AerothermalDemise.pdf. Application is Missile Defense Safety. For the record I am a person with a chemistry degree who is doing programming work, I have a decent grasp of math up to around the intro to differential equations area, past that it starts getting fuzzy.

Comment: Hmmm... missile defense safety? Sounds like a lost cause to me. When the missiles are flying, the chit has already hit the fan.

Comment: True, but this is for range tests. You don't want to accidentally kill someone during a test, bad publicity and such, but you don't want to be too conservative because then you never get to test anything. Turns out aircraft safety is a particularly difficult thing to predict accurately.

Comment: If you can do this test, you are the US government, which means you can also get everybody out of the way. If they don't listen, you have F-15s to make them. :-)

Comment: Ha! I don't feel like I can comment much further on that, but you'll have to trust me that there is a reasonable reason for this analysis.